# Update UI in middle of thread execution c# android

Tags: c#, java, android, multithreading

I am currently migrating java code for my android app to C#. I want to update my UI in middle of thread execution.

Here is my java code:-

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
      if (msg.what == MSG_SURFACE_CREATED) {
        contentWidth = 0;
        contentHeight = 0;
        requestLayout();
        return true;
      } else {
        Log.w("Unknown msg.what: " + msg.what);
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

And:-

```
void postChangedToView(final int indexInAdapter) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            changedToView(indexInAdapter, true);
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried something like this in c# :-

```
private Android.OS.Handler handler = new Android.OS.Handler();

private class Callback : Android.OS.Handler.ICallback //inner class 
{

    ViewController fp;    //Create instance of outer class 
    public Callback(FViewController _fp) //pass the instance to constructor of inner class
    {
        fp = _fp;
    }
    #region ICallback implementation

    public bool HandleMessage (Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.What == MSG_SURFACE_CREATED)
        {
            contentWidth = 0;
            contentHeight = 0;

            fp.RequestLayout ();   

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.w("Unknown msg.what: " + msg.What);
        }
        return false;
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

Here I cannot make an inline class of Handler.ICallBack

And:-

```
internal virtual void postChangedToView(int indexInAdapter) {
    handler.Post (Task.Run (()=> flippedToView (indexInAdapter,true)));
}
```

Here I get an error saying :-

```
Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Action'
```

Comment: I think its purely android related question, why tagged c# ?

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S I am trying to develop the app on xamarin

Comment: he try to convert Android to C#, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Handler.Post` requires a `System.Action` parameter. You can create `System.Action` as below:

```
internal virtual void postFlippedToView(int indexInAdapter)
{
    Action action = () => flippedToView(indexInAdapter, true);
    handler.Post (action );
}
```

Comment: thans for your reply it worked for me. However can you tell me how I can use the callback in the handler like in my java code??

Comment: .Net does not support something like "on the fly" override methods like those of Java. If you want it to be something closer...

handler.Post((Action)(() => flippedToView(indexInAdapter, true)));

Comment: Yeah you answer did work for the second part of the code however any idea how i can use the above class Callback with the handler in the first part? I need to make something like private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {